# Calling function of Exe project in referenced aticvex project in vb6

Tags: vb6, exe, activex

Calling function of Exe project in referenced aticvex project in vb6

I have one AtiveX project in VB6 (Lets call it A )

i have another Exe project in VB6  (Lets call it B )

Project A is referenced in Project B

but now i have a requirement that i want to call function of B inside A

is there a way Can we do it in VB6?

if yes what do i need to search.Already tried searching on Google but not sure i could explain what to search

As i didn't work much on VB6 so i am kind a stuck here what to do

Comment: An ActiveX exe could do the trick (circular reference!) or another VB project with all the common procedures of projects A and B.

Comment: To add to what @Smith said: it depends on _what_ that function in B _does_. i.e. does it directly affect the state of B('s data) or is it "just" a function that returns a value which then can be utilized elsewhere, If the latter, you could create a separate ActiveX DLL and move oit to there, so that both A & B can reference that DLL. IIf the former, the Win32 API also provides several methods of, such as [Mailslots](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?100794-Using-Mailslots), [Named Pipes](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?649507-VB6-PipeRPC-RPC-Over-Named-Pipes).

Comment: I would suggest moving that function to A.  This way it would be available to both A and B.

Answer (score 0):

First off let me say that when you run into this problem it is often a sign that the code organization could be improved. Perhaps some modules in A actually should be in B, or they could be broken down in a more modular way that would resolve the problem. I would first encourage you to think about the problem this way.

That said, there are technical ways of doing what you want, I've suggested some  examples below.

---

One approach to this is to utilize an interface. The interface would be provided by A.dll and the class used to implement it is provided by B.exe.

This is rough pseudocode just to sketch out the concept.

**Within project A:**

Create a *class* to act as an interface (called `ISample`). Within `ISample` have at least one sub or function defined, so you would have `ISample.SomeProcedure`.

Elsewhere in project A, you need some property or procedure `SomeClassInA.RunSampleFunction` which will accept an object of type `ISample` and then call `SomeFunction`.

**Within project B:**

Create another class `SampleImplementation` which `Implements` the `ISample` interface. This means it will have an actual concrete implementation of `SomeFunction`.

From B, create a new object of type `SampleImplementation` and then pass it to the code in A:

```
Dim impl As SampleImplementation
Dim objectFromA As SomeClassInA

Set impl = New SampleImplementation
Set objectFromA As New SomeClassInA

' Pass the object from B to A, where A can call its methods:
objectFromA.SomeProcedure impl
```

This avoids circular references and is a generally object-oriented pattern which I've used before. I will note however that the interface concept in VB6 has some annoyances that you'll have to live with, but for something like this it can be a good tool.

---

A different approach would be to have a class in A which exposes an **event**. You can then declare an object from that class in B using `WithEvents` and attach an event handler to the class. The event handler is just a procedure which exists in B, but now can be called by A.

Events in VB6 also have some limitations (specifically that the WithEvents object has to be within global scope IIRC) but you can usually live with / work around those problems as well.

---

The interface approach may be more general and a more powerful way to share information between A and B, but the event approach could be quicker to get working. Depends a lot on the specifics of what you need to accomplish.

Comment: i am getting this error "A property or method call cannot include a reference to private object"

Comment: you need to post more information to understand the error

Comment: i have implement the interface as you mentioned in solution , i get error on this line "objectFromA.SomeProcedure impl"

Comment: any idea with these information ?

Comment: I think it means that the CLASS `impl` has to be public

Comment: imp class is class module in VB6 and isnt it public ? or how can we make it public